# How to remove product info/collateral box from the product page with Layout XML

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I'm trying to remove the *product info/collateral box* from the product page.  I've tried using the below methods without success:

```
<layout>    
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <!--<remove name="info_tabs" />-->
            <!--<remove name="product.info.tabs" />-->
            <!--<action method="unsetChild"><name>info_tabs</name></action>-->
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.tabs</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I'm using the `<reference name="product.info">` as it is used in the parent theme's.

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <!-- Add tabs -->
    <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml">
```

Im able to remove the *product info/collateral box* by just commenting the below section of code out of the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template, but this not seem to be the best practice.

```
<div class="row product-collateral">
    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can remove this with Layout XML?

Comment: you start your layout file with `</layout>` , that's a closing tag

Comment: @Anja, thanks but that typo was just in the question, not in my code

Comment: in which file are you adding the layout?  the code should be `<remove name="product.info.tabs" />`.. maybe try adding it in local.xml or catalog.xml?

Comment: I'm adding the code in local.xml

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">            
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <alias>description</alias>
        </action>
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <alias>reviews</alias>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Also add more action which you want to remove and in alias use name which use in block 'as'.